# attributes with variable length

Tags: product-attribute

I have a problem how to configure a product (its attribute) with variable lengths. 
Its similar like a ladder. Some are fix, some can be extended and some can be extended only in fix lengths.

- Ladder A, length = 350 cm
- Ladder B, length = 200 - 380 cm
- Ladder C, length = 480, 580, 680 cm

I want to offer the user the right product for his preferred length. Eg.

- Search A needs 350 cm = Ladder A and B
- Search B needs 281 cm = Ladder B

My Problem: Ladder A and C is easy to set up. But how could I make it for Ladder B? When I create 180 values like 200, 201, 202 and so on, I will probably crash my performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT create configurable product in your case. You should look at "Custom Options"(in M1)/"Customizable Options"(in M2) instead.

For M1: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html

For M2: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-custom-options.html

Comment: Not sure how this can help me... The length of the ladder is an characteristic (attribute). And I would like to enable users to find all matching ladders for their special need (in this case length)... I don't get it how I could achieve this with custom options...